# New operator followed by address?

Tags: c++, new-operator

What is the following code doing?

```
int a;
int *b;
b = new (&a) int(5);
```

is it equivalent to:

```
int a;
int *b;
a = 5;
b = new int(a);
```

?

Comment: No, these aren't equivalent. Lookup _placement new_.

Comment: The first block of code is equivalent to `int a; int* b; a = 5; b = &a;`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are *NOT* equivalent. The second one allocates memory and constructs an object of the given type in that memory, then returns the address of that memory. In your example, that address is stored in `b`.

The first variant is called *placement new* and assumes that storage has already been allocated at the address pointed to by the parameter (`&a` in your case) and will then construct an object of the given type at that address. It will return `&a`. Also, to destruct an object constructed by *placement new*, the destructor must manually be called.

So the first variant allocates memory and constructs an object, whereas the second only constructs an object in previously allocated memory.

See here for details: https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/new

Answer (score 0):

`b = new (&a) int(5);` means `new` will construct your object at the given address `&a` (here `b == &a`)

so no, it's not equivalent to `b = new int(a)` (here, `b != &a`)

Comment: Not quite correct, *placement new* does not *allocate*, it only *constructs* an object at the provided address.

Comment: Objects are not allocated. Storage for objects is allocated and objects are then initialized (constructed, created) in this storage.

Comment: Yes, bad word choice